# Thousand separator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

Is there a way to make a thousand separator when typing numbers in a `TextFormField` in flutter?
This is my `TextFormField`

```
child: TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
     border: const OutlineInputBorder()),
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) flutter package

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

Now use `NumberFormat`

```
 var formatter = new NumberFormat("#,###");
  print(formatter.format(1234)), // this will be: 1,234
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @Abion47 works well except if your value contains decimal places. This adaptation handles decimals too.

```
class ThousandsSeparatorInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const separator = ','; // Change this to '.' for other locales

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Short-circuit if the new value is empty
    if (newValue.text.length == 0) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    }

    // Handle "deletion" of separator character
    String oldValueText = oldValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');
    String newValueText = newValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');

    if (oldValue.text.endsWith(separator) &&
        oldValue.text.length == newValue.text.length + 1) {
      newValueText = newValueText.substring(0, newValueText.length - 1);
    }

    // Only process if the old value and new value are different
    if (oldValueText != newValueText) {
      // Split the string into its integer and decimal parts
      List<String> parts = newValueText.split('.');

      int selectionIndex =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.extentOffset;// + (parts.length > 1 ? parts[1].length : 0);
      final chars = parts[0].split('');

      String newString = '';
      for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((chars.length - 1 - i) % 3 == 0 && i != chars.length - 1)
          newString = separator + newString;
        newString = chars[i] + newString;
      }

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString.toString() + (parts.length > 1 ? '.' + parts[1] : ''),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: newString.length - selectionIndex + (parts.length > 1 ? parts[1].length + 1 : 0),
        ),
      );
    }

    // If the new value and old value are the same, just return as-is
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything built into Flutter to handle this. You will have to roll with your own customized text formatter. (Derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869066/1255873).)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ThousandsSeparatorInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const separator = ','; // Change this to '.' for other locales

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Short-circuit if the new value is empty
    if (newValue.text.length == 0) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    }

    // Handle "deletion" of separator character
    String oldValueText = oldValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');
    String newValueText = newValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');

    if (oldValue.text.endsWith(separator) &&
        oldValue.text.length == newValue.text.length + 1) {
      newValueText = newValueText.substring(0, newValueText.length - 1);
    }

    // Only process if the old value and new value are different
    if (oldValueText != newValueText) {
      int selectionIndex =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.extentOffset;
      final chars = newValueText.split('');

      String newString = '';
      for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((chars.length - 1 - i) % 3 == 0 && i != chars.length - 1)
          newString = separator + newString;
        newString = chars[i] + newString;
      }

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString.toString(),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: newString.length - selectionIndex,
        ),
      );
    }

    // If the new value and old value are the same, just return as-is
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [ThousandsSeparatorInputFormatter()],
),
```

Example: https://codepen.io/Abion47/pen/mdVLgGP

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped